# How to match String using pathPrefix/rawPathPrefix in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

This works:

```
rawPathPrefix("Ad(" ~ LongNumber ~ ")") { id =>
```

`id` is now a `Long`, but this doesn't work:

```
rawPathPrefix("Ad(" ~ String ~ ")") { id =>
```

`id` is now a `RequestContext`, not a `String`?

Comment: Try Segment instead of String

Comment: You have some examples using regex: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html#examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a regex pattern that captures one or more characters between `Ad(` and `)` in the path prefix:

```
pathPrefix("""Ad\((.+)\)""".r) { id =>
  ...
}
```

For example, `id` is the string `"12-34b"` for a request sent to:

```
http://host:port/Ad(12-34b)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Segment.

```
path("hello"/Segment)
```

Check this:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html#examples

Comment: Nope, compiles but doesn't match: rawPathPrefix("(" ~ Segment ~ ")") { id =>

Comment: @Rory, Can you tell me the path which you are trying to match?

Comment: Path is: Ad(12-34b)